# R Shiny: Set default value for reactive filter

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I set up a filter by year using year_filter and would like the default view to be 2021. How to do I this given the code below? Currently, the default display is to show all data entries for all years.

The complete code and file can be found here for reference: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1C7SWkl8zyGXLGEQIiBEg4UsNQ5GDaKoa?usp=sharing

Thank you for your assistance!

```html
# Define UI for application
ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$div(
        style = "padding: 10px;",
        # Application title
        titlePanel("Testing and Quarantine Measures"),
        fluidRow(
            uiOutput("CountryFilter_ui"),
            uiOutput("YearFilter_ui")
        ),
        fluidRow(
            tags$div(style = "width: 100%; overflow: scroll; font-size:80%;",
                DT::dataTableOutput('travel_table')
            )
        )
    )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
    
    # Render UI
    output$CountryFilter_ui <- renderUI({
        countries <- travel_clean %>% 
            pull(country_area)
        
        selectInput('country_filter', 'Member State Filter', choices = countries, multiple = TRUE)
    })
    output$YearFilter_ui <- renderUI({
      year <- travel_clean %>% 
        pull(year)
      
      selectInput('year_filter', 'Year Filter', choices = year, multiple = TRUE)
    })
    
    
    # Filter data
    
    travel_filtered <- reactive({
        tmp_travel <- travel_measures %>% 
            select(-Sources)
        if(is.null(input$country_filter) == FALSE) {
            tmp_travel <- tmp_travel %>% 
                filter(`Country/area` %in% input$country_filter)
        }
        return(tmp_travel)
    })
    travel_filtered <- reactive({
      tmp_travel <- travel_measures %>% 
        select(-Sources)
      if(is.null(input$year_filter) == FALSE) {
        tmp_travel <- tmp_travel %>% 
          filter(`Year` %in% input$year_filter)
      }
      return(tmp_travel)
    })
```

Comment: Where is `travel_table` defined in `server` ? Also can you provide necessary data required to make the post reproducible ?

Comment: Hi, the Rcode and file can be found here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1C7SWkl8zyGXLGEQIiBEg4UsNQ5GDaKoa?usp=sharing

Comment: I'd really suggest adding a sample of your data in the snippet above. It's much easier for people looking to answer your question to copy and paste your code from SO, then navigate to other sites, click through links, copy&paste and reformat.

Comment: Do you want `selected="2021"` as an argument in your `selectInput('year_filter')`?

Comment: Yes, "2021" as the default display.